# Make a call on/to/at

Tags: grammar

Please let me know which one I should use. 
E.g) I made a call on/to/at 304xxxxxxx.
Call(text) me on/to/at 304xxxxxxx.
Is it on, to, or at? Or none of them?

Comment: You make a call _to_ a number; you call a person _on_ a number.

Comment: And you text a person **at** a number.